# Can't make the navbar menu flex-direction: column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I think the problem is in the way I made the "container" element, it doesn't let the menu in the navbar expand in column.
I tried removing every height element, even commented the whole container, still nothing.

I want to transform the "menu" class, in the media query to flex-direction: column

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abril+Fatface&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #070707;
}

main {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.nav-bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu>a:hover {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.card-h1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu,
.logo {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-family: "Abril Fatface", cursive;
}


/* .logo {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
} */

.menu {
  width: 25vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/* Hamburger menu */

.menu-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.75rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30px;
  height: 21px;
}

.menu-button .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #070707;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/* Main Container */

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.section1,
.section2,
.section3 {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 33.3333%;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /* Layered Box Shadow */
  /* box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12),
    0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12),
    0 16px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12); */
}

h1,
p {
  font-family: "PT Serif", serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

p {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  padding: 30px;
}

.footer {
  height: 5vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.copywright {
  padding: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 0.6rem;
}

@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .nav-bar {
    width: 80vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .menu-button {
    display: flex;
  }
  .menu {
    display: flex;
    /* display: none; */
  }
  .menu>a {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1rem;
    right: 30%;
    display: flex;
  }
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 80vw;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .section1,
  .section2,
  .section3 {
    width: 80vw;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="nav-bar">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html">andyprv.dev</a>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="menu-button">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </a>
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="https://github.com/andreiprv" target="blank">my.work</a>
        <a href="">contact.me</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section1">
        <div class="card-h1">
          <h1 class="title1">Title Text</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card-p">
          <p class="sub-title1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga porro suscipit voluptatem! Modi placeat beatae porro, id ut maxime veritatis suscipit maiores assumenda dolores. Illum animi provident quae eos voluptate!
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="section2">
        <div class="card-h1">
          <h1 class="title2">Title Text</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card-p">
          <p class="sub-title2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga porro suscipit voluptatem! Modi placeat beatae porro, id ut maxime veritatis suscipit maiores assumenda dolores. Illum animi provident quae eos voluptate!
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="section3">
        <div class="card-h1">
          <h1 class="title3">Title Text</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card-p">
          <p class="sub-title3">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga porro suscipit voluptatem! Modi placeat beatae porro, id ut maxime veritatis suscipit maiores assumenda dolores. Illum animi provident quae eos voluptate!
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-last">
      <p class="copywright">Created by Andrei Ionescu 2020</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want your menu items *vertical* when the media query styles are active.

I think your problem was that you were setting `flex-direction: column` on the menu *items* (`.menu a`) and not the menu itself:

```
.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Here's an example snippet, run it in full screen and adjust the window size to test the behaviour:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abril+Fatface&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #070707;
}

main {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.nav-bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu>a:hover {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.card-h1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu,
.logo {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-family: "Abril Fatface", cursive;
}


/* .logo {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
} */

.menu {
  width: 25vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/* Hamburger menu */

.menu-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.75rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30px;
  height: 21px;
}

.menu-button .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #070707;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/* Main Container */

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.section1,
.section2,
.section3 {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 33.3333%;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /* Layered Box Shadow */
  /* box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12),
    0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12),
    0 16px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12); */
}

h1,
p {
  font-family: "PT Serif", serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

p {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  padding: 30px;
}

.footer {
  height: 5vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.copywright {
  padding: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 0.6rem;
}

@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .nav-bar {
    width: 80vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .menu-button {
    display: flex;
  }
  .menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* display: none; */
  }
  .menu>a {
    display: flex;
  }
  .footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1rem;
    right: 30%;
    display: flex;
  }
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 80vw;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .section1,
  .section2,
  .section3 {
    width: 80vw;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="nav-bar">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html">andyprv.dev</a>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="menu-button">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </a>
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="https://github.com/andreiprv" target="blank">my.work</a>
        <a href="">contact.me</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section1">
        <div class="card-h1">
          <h1 class="title1">Title Text</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card-p">
          <p class="sub-title1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga porro suscipit voluptatem! Modi placeat beatae porro, id ut maxime veritatis suscipit maiores assumenda dolores. Illum animi provident quae eos voluptate!
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="section2">
        <div class="card-h1">
          <h1 class="title2">Title Text</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card-p">
          <p class="sub-title2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga porro suscipit voluptatem! Modi placeat beatae porro, id ut maxime veritatis suscipit maiores assumenda dolores. Illum animi provident quae eos voluptate!
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="section3">
        <div class="card-h1">
          <h1 class="title3">Title Text</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card-p">
          <p class="sub-title3">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga porro suscipit voluptatem! Modi placeat beatae porro, id ut maxime veritatis suscipit maiores assumenda dolores. Illum animi provident quae eos voluptate!
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-last">
      <p class="copywright">Created by Andrei Ionescu 2020</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```